# Animation exported to Unity is always Default Take

Tags: animation, unity

I have a simple character with three actions: MeleeHit, Walk and Default (one frame on T-pose). I am importing to Unity using the .blend file, not exporting it as FBX. MeleeHit and Default appear as they should on Unity, but Walk is shown as DefaultTake.

[image]

I tried to change the name of Walk in Blender and it still was as Default Take in Unity. Even if I delete the animation and create it again with the name "Walk" it will be the Default Take.

I've been trying to figure this out for hours now, if someone could just point me at the right direction I would appreciate.

I think it's also worth mentioning that I'm not an artist (I'm a programmer) so I don't know much about blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it I first created a pose called "0T-pose" (zero is the first character so it is at the top of the action list in Blender), selected it as the current pose and exported the file as FBX (Binary). Idk why it didn't work before. I hope this helps someone with the same problem I hade.

(followed instructions from [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/5ctqq6/change_default_take_in_fbx_export/))

Answer (score 0):

When you import the model into Unity, a "Default Take" is included in the .FBX. It shouldn't matter if you're directly importing the .blend or .FBX, the default take is created. The default take would include all of the keyframes.

Basically, in Unity you then create additional animations clips (walk, melee), all of these are created based on this Default Take.
When you create additional animation clips in Unity, the source take is usually always the "Default Take", because this is the master source for all animations.

You should end up seeing something like this for the clips:

- CLIP           RANGE       SOURCE TAKE
- Default Take   0 to 100    Default Take (master take)
- Walk           27 to 50    Default Take
- MeleeHit       -1 to 26    Default Take